# Apache POI reads the first row but throws null pointer exception for the rest

Tags: java, excel, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

Hi I have a excel sheet with 3 rows and 1 column. Each of the rows contains a ten digit number in General format in excel. This is the code that I have written,

```
public class Tempclass {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int[][] data;
    data = excelRead();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        finddetails(data[i][0]);

    }

    public static int[][] excelRead() throws Exception {

    File excel = new File("C:\\test.xls");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    HSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet("xyz");

    int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum()+1;
    int colNum = ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    int[][] data = new int[rowNum][colNum];

    for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {

        HSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i);         

        for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
            HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(i,Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
            int value = cellToString(cell);
            data[i][j] = value;

        }

    }
    return data;

}

public static int cellToString(HSSFCell cell) {

    int type;
    Object result;

    type = cell.getCellType();
    switch (type) {
    case 0: // numeric value in excel
        result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
        System.out.println("this is case 0" + result);
        break;
    case 1: // String value in excel
        result = cell.getStringCellValue();
        break;
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException("There are no support for this type of cell");
    }
    double z = (double) result;
    int y = (int) z;
    System.out.println("Value of y is" + y);
    return y;}}
```

the finddetails(data[i][0]) method is the actual logic of what I want to achieve but the problem is in the excelRead method  **HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(i,Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);** throws a null pointer exception which is now handled in my switch case. I saw plenty of post on how to handle null cells but there are no null cells in my excel sheet. I wrote some test code to identify the above mentioned line of code as the one causes the exception. Also the code works just fine for the first row, second row onwards getcell returns a null leading to the exception. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Don't forget that rows can also be null!

Answer (score 2):

`HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(i,Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);`

should be -

`HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j,Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);`

you pass column number in `getCell()` not row number.

Comment: Thank you Raman, feels stupid to have spend so much time and finally it was this oversight. Thanks nevertheless.